# Differences in Microsofts C++ STL for Windows CE?

Tags: c++, stl, windows-ce

anyone know of a complete list of the differences in Microsofts implementation of STL for Windows CE, compared to the full STL for desktop? I am using WinCE 6.0, with VS 2005.

I am a bit suprised that they seem to have removed so many things; for GCC it is almost the same. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of CE are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [Standard C++ Library Reference for Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehass7h%28VS.80%29.aspx), the (only) differences are:

### New Functionality

[Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22z6066f(VS.80).aspx) support has been added to this version of the Standard C++ Library.

### Unsupported Functionality

- The Standard C++ Library for devices does not include locale support.
- `uncaught_exception` is only supported on Windows CE 5.0 and higher versions, including Windows Mobile 2005 platforms.

### Unsupported Headers

The device version of the Standard C++ Library does not support the following headers:

- `<cerrno>`
- `<csignal>`
- `<locale>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I encountered more differences when it comes to Windows Mobile. Some string related functions from C were taken out. I can't remember which, there is one year since I discovered that.

Comment: yes - see "unsupported categories in Windows CE C Run-time Libraries" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859579.aspx) and "C run-time functions supported by Windows CE" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859613.aspx). but the question was about C++ STL for CE.

Comment: Thanks, I always find it extremely hard to find these kind of overview articles on MSDN. I was starting to wonder when I couldn't use streams...