# STL containers support for Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, stl, windows-mobile

After days of debugging my Windows Mobile application I have came to a conclusion that the error I get is simply caused by `std::list` code which I have added.

Just after adding this small piece of code :

```
std::list<int> x;
x.push_back(234);
```

My application crushes.

Therefore my question arises : Which of the STL's containers can be used in Windows Mobile and which cannot ?

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373540/differences-in-microsofts-c-stl-for-windows-ce) but i do not find it useful for my problem.

Comment: Oh dear, corrupted the heap again.

Comment: @HansPassant What do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Patryk: Noobie question, but are you initializing (allocating memory for) your list?

Comment: @jp2code As far as I know one do not have to allocate memory for `std::list` `std::vector` etc. Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

If your program compiles and links fine, there shouldn't be anything missing or crashing (for removed or unsupported stuff you should expect a compiler error (e.g. "unknown variable/function/whater" or some kind of preprocessor warning/error). It's more likely there's some other screw up in your code. Have you tried to reproduce the issue using a minimal program?

Comment: The only thing I have checked is that as soon as I add some code with STL container, my program still compiles but I get a PInvoke error - as my C++ dll library is linked to my C# Windows Mobile application.

Comment: Ew! That might be the reason. You're probably trying to mix and match STL stuff from debug and release builds or similar things. Are you somehow trying to use or link older/newer code (e.g. VS2010 + VS2008)?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I have one solution and projects included in my VS2008 solution. [Something like this](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/9162/mobile1.png)

Comment: so the C# DLL no longer is able to call the C++ method?  What is the method signature?

Comment: @ctacke `extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport)  processImage(const char* in_file, const char * out_file);` This is what you wanted to know ? And then in C# code : `[DllImport("DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "processImage")]`
        `private static extern int _ProcessImage(byte[] in_file, byte[] out_file);`

Comment: Think that looks fine. The error is most likely somewhere in your C++ code (possibly some buffer overrun or whatever).

Comment: @Mario As I have said : Everything is just fine until I add code from `std::list` or other STL container. Maybe there is some memory allocation issue on Windows Mobile ?

Comment: I'm not really sure on this. Maybe it's something happening somewhere else. In general, I wouldn't expect this to be a bug they haven't found (as it would be too obvious). Have you tried a minimal example? Like just creating a list in your native code, without doing anything else?